# How to restrict Object migration in GC?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

Can we restrict object migration from one generation to other?

We know  that once Generation 0 is full objects moved to Generation 1 and so on

Suppose if we want to restrict migration of G0 to G1 for perticular object IS IT POSSIBLE?

If YES then please give suitable example.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? This sounds like the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Not with .net, also I don't see how this would be useful.

Comment: that was question in one of my interview, I knew developer don't have any control on it but somehow I was confused in the interview n I wanted to get it clarified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question: *"We know that once Generation 0 is full objects moved to Generation 1 and so on"* - in fact, it's not true. 
Generation 1 holds objects that was inspected by GC **once** and survived, and Generation 2 holds objects survived **two or more** garbage collections.

There is no criteria like "some generation is full" in .NET garbage collection. Thus, based on definitions of G1 and G2 - it is pretty obvious that you can't prevent migration of your objects from G0 to G1 - as if object will survive garbage collection, it **will** be moved into G1.

Comment: Thanks Andy
that was question in one of my interview, I knew developer don't have any control on it but somehow I was confused in the interview n I wanted to get it clarified